# Check if NVARCHAR column can be converted to VARCHAR column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I'm working on a SQL Server 2016 Database which has a table with 730m rows in and growing by around 3m per day. One of the columns is defined as `NVARCHAR(MAX)` and contains XML. I would like to alter this column to be `VARCHAR(MAX)`.

```
alter table [tablename] alter column ExtendedMessage  Varchar(MAX) NOT NULL
```

Problem is I need to check if any of the data in this column would be invalid for the narrowing conversion from `NVARCHAR` to `VARCHAR`.

Without just trying it, is there a way to test if any of the data will cause the statement to fail?

**Platform**: SQL Server 2016 Enterprise.

Comment: Find out the number of `?` characters in the `nvarchar`, and compare it to the number of `?` characters in the converted `varchar` value. If they differ, then the was a loss of data.

Comment: If it's XML why don't you use the `xml` data type

Comment: Thanks @Larnu. I'll experiment with this. Because of the quantity/load on the table, i'll have to perform the check in tranches. I'll try something like "where len(ExtendedMessage) <> len(cast(ExtendedMessage as varchar(max))

Comment: thanks @Charlieface. There is a small percentage of data that goes into this column that isn't xml but is still text based. I need to do some additional research on this data type and the exact reason for having non-xml in this column to understand if we can use it

Comment: That won't work, @Matt . The `LEN` of an `nvarchar` and a `varchar` would still be the same if a character is replaced. `N'Cönàn'`and `'C?n?n'` have the same length (I am not saying that characters would be lost, just using an example)

Comment: Sounds like a design flaw, @Matt . The XML should be in an `xml` column and the non-XML data in a different column.

Comment: Would be slow as all get out but you would need something like this. where len(replace(ExtendedMessage, '?', '')) <> len(cast(replace(ExtendedMessage, '?', '') as varchar(max))

Comment: Even if you perform a test and it appears it will not result in a loss of data - is that because it's *not possible*, or because the first insert of such data isn't going to happen until ~1 hour after you make this change; it was always possible? You cannot reliably reason from the data, you need to look at the actual source and work out what it is or isn't capable of including in that data.

Comment: Thanks for all of the comments above for your suggestions and help - it wont allow me to tag all of you :(. I have run a query based on the above suggestions over a sample of 5m records and around 1 in every 100,000 records has an extended character in it. We have control over the multitude of input channels so will over time be able to block extended characters from being entered.

Comment: Late to the party, but: there is really no good reason to do this. If storage is the issue, use [compression](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/data-compression/data-compression) (row, page or even columnstore compression, though the latter has a lot more impact on performance of modifications). Changing the type will not enforce that data can't be stored or throw up an error or anything like that -- it will simply enable silent mangling of values for no benefit whatsoever (save for storage, but like I said there are better options for that).